# How optimize little code React "RandomImage" from array with onclick

Tags: reactjs

I make a little code for take array images and show one and change it with click, but I think that code can be more optimized, especialy the second useState but I dont know how.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const apiURL = 'https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=100';

export default function Image() {
  function random(mn, mx) {
    return Math.random() * (mx - mn) + mn;
  }
  const [gifs, setgifs] = useState([]);
  useEffect(function () {
    console.log('test');
    fetch(apiURL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        const gifs = response.map((image) => image.download_url);
        setgifs(gifs);
      });
  }, []);
  let imagenaleatoria = gifs[Math.floor(random(1, gifs.length))];
  const [imagenactual, nuevaimagen] = useState();

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <section className='App-header'>
        <div className='caja'>
          <img
            onClick={() => {
              nuevaimagen(gifs[Math.floor(random(1, gifs.length))]);
            }}
            src={imagenaleatoria}
          ></img>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I just rewrite your code snippet and add comments so you understand what and why

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const apiURL = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=100";
// has no acces to state so there is no need to create this funtion isde the RandomImage component
export const getRandomIndex = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};

export const RandomImage = () => {
  const [gifs, setGifs] = useState([]);
  const [randomIndex, setRandomIndex] = useState(null);

  // runs only after the first render
  useEffect(function () {
    console.log("test");
    fetch(apiURL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        const gifs = response.map((image) => image.download_url);
        setGifs(gifs);
        setRandomIndex(getRandomIndex(0, gifs.length));
      });
  }, []);
  
  // just sets an random index 
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setRandomIndex(getRandomIndex(0, gifs.length));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section className="App-header">
        <div className="caja">
            {!gifs.length ? (
                'Loading...'
            ) : (
                <img onClick={handleClick} src={gifs[randomIndex]} />
            )}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```